# Splitting a set of strings and storing in a dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a set of values like below from doing a split of strings

```
var values = [
  "Budget1-green", 
  "Team1-green", 
  "Risk1-green", 
  "Benefit1-green", 
  "Scope1-green",
  "Schedule1-green"
];
```

I want to be able to store the values after the `-` in a variable like below. Any ideas on how to do this with javascript or jQuery?

```
var Budget1   = 'green';
var Team1     = 'green';
var Risk1     = 'green';
var Benefit1  = 'green';
var Scope1    = 'green';
var Schedule1 = 'green';
```

Comment: You can store it in an object

Comment: Thanks Akshay. Do you have code sample?

Comment: Do you really want/need them in the global scope so you can access them by the name like `Budge1` or `Team1`?

Comment: I want to be able to access them one by one and store in a database. I dont think the object will work.

Comment: "I dont think the object will work" - why it won't ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

This loops through each element in the array , splits it , and stores it as an object. Later you can call these values like this

```
objVariables["Budget1"] // returns green
```

```js
var values = ["Budget1-green", "Team1-green", "Risk1-green", "Benefit1-green", "Scope1-green", "Schedule1-green"];
var objVariables = {};
for(var x=0;x<values.length;x++){
  var splitted = values[x].split("-");
  objVariables[splitted[0]] = splitted[1];
}
console.log(objVariables);

// Calling each variables 
// They all will return green since it is the data you have given 

console.log(objVariables["Budget1"]);
console.log(objVariables["Team1"]);
console.log(objVariables["Risk1"]);
console.log(objVariables["Benefit1"]);
console.log(objVariables["Scope1"]);
```

Comment: This is very straight forward and works for me. Big thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

try this (store in one variable which is a map with values before - as key)

```js
var values = ["Budget1-green", "Team1-green", "Risk1-green", "Benefit1-green", "Scope1-green", "Schedule1-green"];


var map = {}; values.forEach( function(val){ 
  var split = val.split("-"); map[ split[0] ] = split[1]; 
});

console.log(map);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save values in object.

#### Array.forEach

```js
var values = ["Budget1-green", "Team1-green", "Risk1-green", "Benefit1-green", "Scope1-green", "Schedule1-green"]

var result = {}

values.forEach(function(item){
  var o = item.split("-");
  result[o[0]] = o[1];
});

document.write("<pre>" +JSON.stringify(result,0,4)+ "</pre>")
```

#### for...of

```js
var values = ["Budget1-green", "Team1-green", "Risk1-green", "Benefit1-green", "Scope1-green", "Schedule1-green"]

var result = {}

for(var item of values){
  var o = item.split("-");
  result[o[0]]=o[1];
}

document.write("<pre>" +JSON.stringify(result,0,4)+ "</pre>")
```

Comment: Downvoter, please share whats missing in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using a non-object approach, in order to get exactly the solution you were looking for, would be as follows (using `eval()` or the window object):

```js
var values = [
  "Budget1-green",
  "Team1-green",
  "Risk1-green",
  "Benefit1-green",
  "Scope1-green",
  "Schedule1-green"
];


// Loop through each array item
for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++)
{
   // This splits the data into separate pieces
   var split_data = values[i].split('-');

   // Here, we assign the dynamic variable using the window object
   // This is the preferred method:
   window[split_data[0]] = split_data[1];

   // Alternatively, you can use `eval` to create the variable
   // This approach is generally unsafe, so use with caution:
   eval("var " + split_data[0] + "=" + split_data[1] + ";");
}
```

Using the window object is the preferred method since `eval` can potentially be dangerous.

Also, be careful when using dynamically-created variables because it can cause confusion if, for example, there was already a variable named "Budget1" in the global scope.

Comment: Do refer following post before using `eval` [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Comment: While this is a correct answer, please note that this is potentially very unsafe.  If the values in the array are taken from user input and not properly sanitized, it could mean that a user can inject malicious code into the javascript that is executed immediately.

Comment: @StephanMuller OP never said anything about input coming from user input.

Comment: this snippet runs with `"message": "Script error.",`

Comment: @WesFoster That's why I'm warning him for 'potentially' unsafe situations. It is the correct answer to OP's question so I did upvote, but I would think twice before putting this in production :)

Comment: @StephanMuller Definitely. I've added a small disclaimer in the code sample

Answer (score 1):

All the answers so far are to add to an object and that works but in case you need/want the global scope you could do this:

```js
var values = ["Budget1-green", "Team1-blue", "Risk1-green", "Benefit1-green", "Scope1-green", "Schedule1-green"];

for(var i = 0, numValues = values.length; i < numValues; ++i) {
  var parts = values[i].split("-");
  window[parts[0]] = parts[1];
}

console.log(Budget1);
console.log(Team1);
console.log(Risk1);
console.log(Benefit1);
console.log(Scope1);
console.log(Schedule1);
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but its not very good programming. There is probably a better way to do what OP wants if we had more details...

Comment: Do mention risks of polluting global scope. Its not a good practice to use global variable

Comment: Yeah, I'd definitely categorize this as a code smell, but so is the original question. It all depends on what OP needs the variables for.

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = ["Budget1-green", "Team1-green", 
       "Risk1-green", "Benefit1-green", "Scope1-green", "Schedule1-green"]

var obj = {};

values.forEach(function(val){       
    obj[val.split("-")[0]] = val.split("-")[1];        
});
```

Below is the fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/hzdwfkue/1/

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new variable name on the fly is possible (using `eval()`) but strongly advised against. Instead, storing the data in an object would be a lot better.

By looping through the array you can do it like this:

```
var myVars = {};

values.forEach(function(value) {
    var split = value.split('-');
    myVars[split[0]] = split[1];
});
```

Now you have an object that looks like:

```
{ 
    Budget1: "green",
    Team1: "green",
    etc...
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to pass each of the items via ajax and store in a database

Comment: That's still possible, it doesn't matter for that whether they are separate variables or all combined in an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by `split` and `eval`.

> The eval() function evaluates or executes an argument or javascript statements.

```
var values = [
  "Budget1-green", 
  "Team1-green", 
  "Risk1-green", 
  "Benefit1-green", 
  "Scope1-green",
  "Schedule1-green"
];
for(var i in values){
  temp = values[i].split("-");
  eval("var "+temp[0]+"='"+temp[1]+"';");
}
console.log(Budget1);//green
console.log(Scope1);//green
```